# How to convert a text file that is already in dictionary format to python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a text file , which is already in dictionary format , having contents like `{'Eggs': 7, 'Peanut': 11, 'Milk': 4, 'Curd': 3}` and many more.
I would like to open this file in python and search for a key and get its value.

Comment: please share text file and code snippet. Just use `json`. It's easy. But, I can't give the code because I have no exact text file sample.

Comment: @yahocho The given file snippet is not valid JSON thus it could lead to errors using json.

Comment: @Yoiro Yes. You are correct. So, I need the exact data.

Comment: @yahocho do you want the whole text file ...or just the text contents inside it ? Reply, so that I can share a link for that file.

Comment: @RaviSRanjan Just sample is ok. Please copy and paste in the question from an editor.

Comment: @yahocho please check the question, i have provided the sample text content which is their inside the text file. 
I want to load the text file in python and suppose i search for  key, i should get its value.

Comment: @yaho-cho  You can also view in dropbox link  https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uf1djnu9vs0xhm/sample.txt?dl=0

Comment: @RaviSRanjan Added answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `'` to `"`.
And, Use `json`.

```
import json

dictdata = {}
with open('d:/workspace/test.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = data.replace('\'', '"')
    dictdata = json.loads(data)
print (dictdata['Gagan Khoda'])
```

The result is:

`16297`

But, Your `sample.txt` missed `'` at the first. I just `'` when I test it in myself.

Comment: Yes i am aware of that  missed '  in the first key.  But the code works fully fine. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#eval) with the content of your file:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
lines = " ".join(map(str.strip, lines))  # We remove the breaklines
result = eval(lines)
print(result, type(result))
```

Prints:

```
{'Eggs': 7, 'Peanut': 11, 'Milk': 4, 'Curd': 3} <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: This gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax .  Kindly refer to the text content  which i am working with...https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uf1djnu9vs0xhm/sample.txt?dl=0